# How to get multi tab view effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following image sums up everything I want to have in my HTML file.

I just want to add tab naming "TAB Name" and "X" close button on top of the tab, like Cover Flow, but vertical.

How can I achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to use that for exactly? And what have you tried?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I will use it to load image .